# Why a single INSERT in MySQL generates an infinite number of insertions?

Tags: php, mysql, insert, infinite-loop, auto-increment

This code

```
<?php

    $link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "...", "password", "...");

    if (mysqli_connect_error()) {

        die ("No database connection.");

    }

    $query = "INSERT INTO users (email, password)
                 VALUES ('hello@hello.com', 'mypassword')";
    if (mysqli_query($link, $query)) {
        echo "New record created successfully.";
    }
?>
```

displays the sentence "New record created successfully." only once correctly, but inserts the same row with a different id forever. I suspect that the problem is related to the AUTO_INCREMENT property of the id field, but I can't understand this behavior.

Comment: show more of your code.

Comment: the loop is not related to the auto_increment property, and neither to the piece of code you shared as well. Something else is causing this issue.

Comment: Check is your query is in any loop?

Comment: No, it's not...

Comment: check the values once.. if you are giving constantly means all the time same values will insert  with autoincrement.

Comment: I edited the question. This is all my code.

Comment: from where you are getting values ??  are you keeping constantly..

Comment: I can't simply insert those values once?

Comment: hmm. try closing your connection once the value is inserted. tell me what happens

Comment: the code which is visible to us is fine.. debug line by line from your end and echo the query when submitting the form may be u got the sollution.

Comment: Is a bot hitting your site? There's nothing limiting the execution here so every page load runs an insert. Check your access logs.

Comment: The problem comes out when I refresh the webpage that displays the echo. If I save the code and check phpMyAdmin there is only one insertion, but if I refresh the webpage that displays the echo, the insertions become thousands.

Comment: Do you have rewrite rules in place? The PHP here wouldn't cause an infinite (or any) loop.

Comment: Is this script being called in another file or something?

Comment: There is only this file with only this code.

Comment: Then show us whole page which loads with meta tags and all other information because we can't help you so far with what you showed us

Comment: The page which loads is a php file with the code that I posted.